# Cloudfront AccessDenied and files are still delivered

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, access-denied, bucket

I want to deliver a JS file through cloudfront using Amazon S3.

I have configure cloudfront to update bucket policy and this policy was generated

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity **********"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The file is delivered so everyone can load it but I have an access denied in the cloudfront logs

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>23EF9D4EF83B9E7B</RequestId>
    <HostId>**************</HostId>
</Error>
```

Why do I have errors if the files are delivered ? Is this error an important one ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your policy is to allow a CloudFront virtual user to access content in buckets whose ACL is private. This means that CloudFront can access the content.

The error message is most likely for users (outside of your normal users) trying to access CloudFront without a referrer header. Look at the CloudFront logs to see what types of requests are being rejected.